# Scaling plots in Rmd via out.width

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I am producing a Rmd document that also includes some plots.  It should export to both, otd and pdf.  Some of the figures should be small enough to fit two of them next to each other in the resulting odt.

I knit the document via

```
Rscript -e "require(knitr); require(markdown); knit('Test_Markdown.Rmd', 'Test_Markdown.md')"
```

In the Rmd there is a plot that looks like this:

````
```{r plottestnormal, fig.path = ".", fig.width = 6, fig.height = 6, dpi = 300, dev = "png", dev.args = list(type = "cairo")}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

I would like the plot to be half size -- but scaled!

This gets the size correct, but not the scaling:

````
```{r plottestsmall, fig.path = ".", fig.width = 3, fig.height = 3, dpi = 600, dev = "png", dev.args = list(type = "cairo")}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

This as I understand from [the opiton description](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) the following should do what I mean, but it does not 'work'.

````
```{r plottestscaled, fig.path = ".", fig.width = 6, fig.height = 6, out.width = 3, out.height = 3, dpi = 300, dev = "png", dev.args = list(type = "cairo")}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

What happens is that this produces an html img tag in the generated *md file:

```
<img src=".plottestscaled-1.png" title="plot of chunk plottestscaled" alt="plot of chunk plottestscaled" width="3" height="3" />
```

And that does not show in either pdf nor odt when compiled with

```
pandoc -f markdown "Test_Markdown.md" -o "Test_Markdown.odt"

pandoc -t latex "Test_Markdown.md" -o "Test_Markdown.pdf"
```

And I have seen [this issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/528) which does not help me further.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Yihui this now works for LaTeX-> pdf and (presumably -- untested) for html.

Am I right, that `out.width` and `out.height` are not supported for `*.odt` or `*.docx` export?

If they are, what might be the reason that they do not work for me?

If they are not, how can I achieve the same effect (scaled plots) in `*.odt`?

(I would like to export to `pdf` and `odt`, so any solution would ideally cover (at least) these two simultaneously.)

Here is a complete doc that shows my problem when processed via `rmarkdown::render("Test_Markdown.Rmd", "all")`.

````
---
title: Scale plot in Rmd
output:
    pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
    odt_document:
        keep_md: true
---

```{r plottestscaled, fig.path = "./", fig.width = 6, fig.height = 6, out.width = "3in", out.height = "3in", dpi = 300, dev = "png", dev.args = list(type = "cairo")}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

EDIT2:

My 'best' solution so far is, to disable the scaling in the `odt` output and to manually rescale the plots in office.  Not very reproducible, though....

````
```{r plottestscaled, fig.path = "./", fig.width = 6, fig.height = 6, out.width=switch(opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to"), latex = "3in", NULL), out.height=switch(opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to"), latex = "3in", NULL), dpi = 300, dev = "png", dev.args = list(type = "cairo")}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc's Markdown did not to support specifying the size of images until very recent versions, so when you specify the width of a plot, **knitr** has to fall back to HTML, and HTML code will not work for LaTeX or ODT output (only native Markdown code is supported, except for LaTeX output, in which raw LaTeX code is also supported).

The short answer is use the **rmarkdown** package instead of running Pandoc by yourself. **knitr** will be smart enough to switch to LaTeX code when generating figures that have the width attributes. Or even better, just click the `Knit` button in the RStudio IDE.

You can try to figure out all the technical details behind the scenes if you want (start from [`knitr::hook_plot_md`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/hooks-md.R)), but it can be overwhelming if you are not familiar with how **knitr** and **rmarkdown** work internally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Using rmarkdown::render() it does indeed work for the LaTeX->pdf route.  That's great!  It does not work for the odt output, though.  Is there a way to achieve the same (scaled plot) in the odt output?  (See also my EDIT above.)

Comment: No, setting figure width in ODT is not supported. I'm not sure if Pandoc supports it. If it does, we can definitely add support in rmarkdown as well.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  In case you are aware of any work-around (or in case this feature becomes available....) I'd be very interested.

Comment: seems to become possible soon.  There is an item on the [v1.21 milestone](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/milestone/35) linking to an open [issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1478).  The issue only mentions word/ppt, though.  Would this also include odt?

Comment: Nex time you can just add it to the issue (I have done so this time).

Comment: @Andreas May this answer help you a bit https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996705/6500804