# RMarkdown plot inserted into Word with 101% width and height

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

Just like in Title: no matter how fancy or simple a plot I insert into Word from RMarkdown, I get an image with 101% height and width. This is annoying because this makes plots look blurred.

**Example**

This short .Rmd file:

````
---
output:
  word_document

---

```{r, echo=F}
plot(1:100)
```
````

knits to this:

[image]

Then I right-click on it, select *Properties* and see it was inserted with 101% of original size (strange language below is polish ;) )

[image]

When I reset it to 100%, it looks much nicer:

[image]

**Question**
How to force RMarkdown to insert plots with 100% width and height?

**What I've tried**

(none of these work)

- change plot size (`fig.width` and `fig.height` chunk options)
- change default unit in Word from cm to in
- change device used for plots and it's resoultion (`dev` and `res` chunk options)

Comment: I performed some tests and I noted that it is a `pandoc` issue and not a `r` or `knitr` issue. I add the `pandoc` tag to the question.

Comment: What is your `pandoc` version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First, note that when [this `knitr` feature request](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1478) will be implemented, you will must stop using the following answer.*

This problem can be solved using `pandoc` [link attributes](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-link_attributes). As explained in the `pandoc` documentation, without link attributes "*the fallback is to look at the image resolution and the dpi metadata embedded in the image file*" (I think the trouble comes from this fallback method).

Link attributes is a recent `pandoc` feature, introduced in `pandoc` 1.16. It is not yet supported by `knitr`, but will be soon according to the above-mentioned feature request.

As long as `knitr` does not support `pandoc` link attributes, here is a hacky proposal to solve this problem. It uses a `knitr` [plot hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output-hooks).

````
---
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
default_plot_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get('plot')

knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
  default_md <- default_plot_hook(x, options)
  link_attr <- sprintf("{width=%sin height=%sin}", options$fig.width, options$fig.height)
  sub("(!\\[.*]\\(.*\\))", paste0("\\1", link_attr), default_md)
})
```

```{r, echo=F}
plot(1:100)
```
````

**Explanations**
The first step of the rendering process of a `RMarkdown` file (`.Rmd`) is to produce a plain `markdown` file (`.md`). *This is the job of `knitr`.*

The second step of the process is to produce the `word` file (`.docx`) from this `markdown` file. *This is the job of `pandoc`.*

Note that you can inspect this intermediate `markdown` file using the `keep_md` option in the `YAML` header:

```
---
output: 
  word_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

With the available versions of `knitr`, a link to an image is rendered by `knitr` like this:

```
![](myreport_files/figure-docx/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png)<!-- -->
```

There is no link attributes, so `pandoc` determines the dimensions of the image using its fallback method.

The proposed `knitr` plot hook add width and height attributes to the link.
It returns the following `markdown`:

```
![](myreport_files/figure-docx/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png){width=5in height=4in}<!-- -->
```

Therefore, `pandoc` determines the dimensions of the image from these attributes and not from the fallback method.

*Obviously, to use this proposal, your `pandoc` version has to be >= 1.16.*

Comment: Almost perfect ;) Your code allows for only integers in fig.width and fig.height. Trying fig.width=4.5 results with an error in spritnf function.

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło I've changed `%i` by `%s`. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Truly perfect now :D